# cross-browsing compatibilty for website

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website using bootstrap ,HTML,CSS,CSS3 and PHP as Server side language. But when i checked it on different Browser I found that it is not compatible for all browser by examining some appearance and functionality of HTML elements. I want my web page should look on every browser.

I wanted to know :

1) What are the aspects that we have to take in consideration while designing cross-browsing website?

2) How can i design a page which can give me the same output on different browser.

Comment: Including IE8 and less or not?

Comment: This question is way too broad.  Entire books can be written on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not at all PHP related. PHP runs on a server and generates (HTML) output. That output must be compatible with the browsers, but it's not specific to PHP to get it that way. Therefor I've removed PHP from your title and tags.

The remaining question:

1. First aspects to take into consideration, is that no two browsers are the same. Even if you have the same browser, they can run on a different machine, have a slightly different update, run on different screen sizes, etcetera.

Also, browsers have their own CSS already built in. A `h1` element has a big bold font. The exact size, family and boldness might vary across browsers. Therefor, many websites will start with a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) (Thanks, @Vucko). This is basically a bunch of CSS code that you can include, which will remove all markup or at least make it the same across browsers.

But even after that, don't aim for pixel perfect. Sometimes nearly is good enough.

This especially goes for unimportant features. For instance, rounded corners and shadows are not supported by old IE browsers, or may look slightly different. Instead of mimicing those CSS features by building big HTML structures and add background images, I think you should cut your losses and accept that a shadow won't show or the corners are squared when otherwise the site works okay.

It's good to follow standards. If you follow standards, and make sure your HTML is valid, it will show nearly the same in most browsers.

There might still be differences, expecially if you use new features that are not fully supported in all browsers. Using features that are widely supported, boils down to a lot of practise, a lot of knowledge, and being able to use at least these sites:

- http://validator.w3.org/ - Check if your site is valid.
- http://caniuse.com/ - Good overview of browser compatibility of specific HTML/CSS features.
- http://www.quirksmode.org/ - A similar site.

Especially those overviews are very helpful. You can see in a glance whether a feature is supported or not, and whether you need special CSS prefixes (like `-webkit-`) in your CSS to make it work for some browsers.

2. The answer is actually the same as for 1: Don't. Make it look good on the most important browsers, and make it work on the less important ones. If a browser is really old, don't care about it. The oldest Windows that is still supported is Vista. Vista will run IE upto version 9. So IE8- users should just upgrade their browser. If you do want to support it, only make it work and look reasonable, but don't try to make it pixel perfect. Don't try to do that in any browser, for that matter.

Comment: +1 maybe you should also mention about [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Comment: I have checked other websites on internet, Most of them are working fine on every browsers including IE 7. is it like , Other website developers are developing browser compatible CSS for each and every browser for one website? like css1 for IE,css2 for Mozila and so on. And after that calling each css conditionally.

Comment: You can fairly easily make exceptions for older IE versions, because IE supports [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). That way, you can include extra CSS files for those browsers. And of course, you can carefully only choose features that are compatible with those browsers, or provide a fallback. It could be that those websites were made a while ago when IE7 was relevant. If you want that too, it's up to you, but your code will have to use 'old' features to be compatible. That makes you less future proof.

Answer (score 1):

1) Before you use any html5 element. Just check on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#). To see if it's compatible with the browsers you want. If you are desperate to use that element, provide error callback or just alternative callback.

2) Use prefixes like `-webkit-` or `-moz-` etc for partially supported  css rules on browsers(you can check on caniuse). If they do not support the rule at all, fallback to  images but mind page load. You can also use cssreset library like normalize.css to standarise default styling across browsers.